# Apply operation on two columns returning 'None'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply an email cleaning function to a column, and record the result in a separate column.

I am not entirely sure how to apply a function to two columns with `.apply()` but here is what I've tried:

First set up the dataframe, and a dictionary of common email mistakes:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'emails':['jim@gmailcom','bob@gmail.com','mary@gmaicom','bobby@gmail.com'],
                   'result':['','','','']})

df

    emails          result
0   jim@gmailcom    
1   bob@gmail.com   
2   mary@gmaicom    
3   bobby@gmail.com 

# common mistakes:

correct_domain = {'gmailcom': 'gmail.com',
 'gmaicom': 'gmail.com',
 'gmaillom': 'gmail.com',
 'gmalcom': 'gmail.com'}
```

Now I want to go through the emails, and replace the mispelled domain with the correct one. Eg. gmailcom -> gmail.com

```
def clean_emails(x):

    # for each domain(key) in this dict ( e.g. 'gmailcom':'gmail.com')
    for mistake in correct_domain:  

        # if incorrect domain ('gmailcom') is in the email we're checking
        if mistake  in x['emails']:

            # replace it with the dict value which is the correctly formatted domain ('gmail.com')
            x['emails'] = x['emails'].replace(mistake ,correct_domain[mistake ])

            # record result
            x['result'] = 'email cleaned'

        else:
            x['result'] = 'no cleaning needed'
```

And then I get None when I apply this function:

```
df.apply(clean_emails,axis=1)

0    None
1    None
2    None
3    None
dtype: object
```

I tried to use `return` into the mix, but was unable to figure out two separate returns for the separate columns.

My desired result, emails have been cleaned and outcome recorded to `result`:

```
    emails          result
0   jim@gmail.com    'email cleaned'    
1   bob@gmail.com   'no cleaning needed'    
2   mary@gmail.com    'email cleaned'   
3   bobby@gmail.com 'no cleaning needed'
```

**edit:** I thought adding `return x` to the end of the function would return the newly edited rows, but emails were not cleaned.

```
    emails  result
0   jim@gmail.com   email cleaned
1   bob@gmail.com   no cleaning needed
2   mary@gmaicom    no cleaning needed
3   bobby@gmail.com no cleaning needed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for check if necessary cleaning with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for column by condition and then use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with call back for replace by dictionary only necessary rows:

```
pat = '|'.join(correct_domain.keys())
m = df['emails'].str.contains(pat, na=False)
df['result'] = np.where(m, 'email cleaned', 'no cleaning needed')
df.loc[m, 'emails'] = (df.loc[m, 'emails']
                         .str.replace(pat, lambda x: correct_domain[x.group()], regex=True))

print (df)
            emails              result
0    jim@gmail.com       email cleaned
1    bob@gmail.com  no cleaning needed
2   mary@gmail.com       email cleaned
3  bobby@gmail.com  no cleaning needed
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this on the full dataset I have.  Some of the emails are NaN and it's throwing an error. `ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values`. How would you get around this? I've been trying different things, like adding an extra mask `mask2 = df['emails'].notnull()` etc. but I'm getting a different error for each different attempt

Comment: @SCool - use `df['emails'].str.contains(pat, na=False)` - add `na=False` parameter

Answer (score 1):

Why not a two-liner:

```
df['result'] = df['emails'].str.contains('|'.join(correct_domain.keys()).map({0:'email cleaned', 1:'no cleaning needed'})
df['emails'] = df['emails'].str.replace('|'.join(correct_domain.keys()),list(correct_domain.values())[0])
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Will be:

```
            emails              result
0    jim@gmail.com       email cleaned
1    bob@gmail.com  no cleaning needed
2   mary@gmail.com       email cleaned
3  bobby@gmail.com  no cleaning needed
```

Comment: Because this is just a small sample of the full cleaning operation. My `clean_emails` function actually has a few more checks that I will add to the function, just wanted to get it up and running. I also want to learn how to do this sort of `apply()` operation even if this instance is not very efficient. With all the checks i want to do, this will just be a long paragraph of line after line. Just wanted to get it into a function.

Comment: @SCool Your code isn't working because you're not returning anything, if you add `return x` it should work

Comment: I tried to do that originally, but if I return the new cleaned email, how to I ensure it returns to the `'emails'` column? And if I want to return the `result` i.e. `email cleaned`, how do I ensure it returns to the `result` column?

Comment: I added `return x` at the end of the function, but it didn't work. I have edited the original question

Comment: @U10-Forward I don't understand the second parameter you pass to str.replace: it will always return the first element of the list, which is fine in this particular case where all list entries are identical, but will fail if they were different (e.g. when the dictionary contains hotmail --> hotmail.com). Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking, I see you already have a lot of solutions on offer. By following your logic we can get there like that:

```py
    df = pd.DataFrame({'emails':['jim@gmailcom','bob@gmail.com','mary@gmaicom','bobby@gmail.com']})

    regexExp = [r'gmailcom$', r'gmaicom$', r'gmaillom', r'gmalcom']

    df2 = df.replace(regex=regexExp, value='gmail.com')

    result = []
    for dfLines, df2Lines in zip(df.itertuples(),df2.itertuples()):
        if df2Lines.emails != dfLines.emails:
            result.append('email cleaned')
        else:
            result.append('no cleaning needed')

    df2['result'] = result

    print(df2)
```